# My kafka topics are not available after kafka restart

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-toolbox

i have a single machine with Windows 10. I installed Docker toolbox, and started my Kafka container using the below command.

```
docker run  -it 
      -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 
      -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 -p 9092:9092 
      -e ADV_HOST=192.168.99.100 
      landoop/fast-data-dev
```

I then created topics and added data to it, but after the restart, my topics are not available. I tried to replicate again, but the behaviour is same.

Please advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the landoop image supports this as it is set up from scratch every time you run it. As they state in the readme:

`Hit control+c to stop and remove everything`

It is supposed to work as a dev and test tool